# Slide-in and out content on same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a slide-in content (not a menu, but the effect is the same) from the left when clicking on the bars icon. I've managed to do it by having one button for opening and another for closing (i.e., moving the page to and back to left). But now, I'm trying to do the same using only one button, so that on first click it opens the content and on the second it closes. I'm new to Javascript/jQuery stuff so I've searched online and tweaked it along the way, trying to make it work.

I have here a test [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8L0hq3r/) so you can see what's wrong and hopefully help me.

**Javascript:**

```
var main = function() {
$('.icon-menu').click(function(){
  $('.menu').toggle(
    function(){
      $('.menu').animate({
        left: "0px"}, 200);
  },
    function(){
      $('.menu').animate({
        left: "600px"}, 200);
  });
});
}; 

$(document).ready(main);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="icon-menu icon-close col-xs-1">
            <i class="fa fa-bars fa-4x"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="row">
         <div class="menu col-md-5">
            <div class="texto-about col-md-offset-1">
                <h1>About</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, quia.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
background-color: grey;
}

.menu {
background-color: blue;
left: -600px;  /* same as width */
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
/*  width: 600px; */
}

.texto-about {
color: #fff;
font-size: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.icon-menu {
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
padding-bottom: 25px;
padding-left: 25px;
padding-top: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 0;
background-color: red; /* just so you know where the button is */
}

.icon-menu i {
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

NOTE: I know that toggle has been deprecated in new versions of jQuery, but it was the only solution I found that related to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in jquery 1.8 the toggle function acts like a click function itself so you don't require a separate click function.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/ue36sfcs/

**Code**

```
 $('.icon-menu').toggle(
    function(){
      $('.menu').animate({
        left: "600px"}, 200);
  },
    function(){
      $('.menu').animate({
        left: "0px"}, 200);
  });
```

For Jquery versions above 1.8 you can set an on, off flag

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/eae779xo/

**Code**

```
var on = "no"
$(document).on("click", ".icon-menu", function(){      
    if (on == "no") { $('.menu').animate({ left: "600px"}, 200);
on = "yes"
}
else { $('.menu').animate({ left: "0px"}, 200);
on = "no"
}
})
```